# Should I say “in drugs” or “on drugs”?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, prepositions

Which one is correct  “in drugs” or “on drugs”? And whats the difference between both.

I am not sure which one is right to use.

Comment: Both are correct. What are you trying to say? They mean different things.

Comment: Can you provide the complete sentence instead of just the phrase?

Comment: Actually, I don't have a sentence just phrase.

Answer (score 1):

On drugs means a person under the influence of drugs.

In drugs could mean that something is inside drugs, maybe hidden in a pack of drugs.